# How does this sed command parse numbers with commas?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm having difficulty understanding a number-parsing sed command I saw in [this article](https://www.linux.com/learn/docs/726140-more-great-linux-awk-sed-and-bash-tips-and-tricks):

```
sed -i ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta' numbers.txt
```

I'm a `sed` newbie, so this is what I've been able to figure out:

- `&` adds to what's already there rather than substitutes
- the `:a; ... ;ta` calls the substitution recursively on the line until the search finds no more returns

Here's what I am hoping folks can explain

- What does `-i` do? I can't seem to find it on the man pages though I'm sure it's there.
- I'm a little fuzzy on what the `\B` is accomplishing here? Perhaps it helps with the left-right parsing priority, but I don't see how. So lastly...
- **Most importantly, why does this execute right to left instead of left to right?** For example, which part of the command keeps this from doing something like: `1234566778,9 --->  1234,566,778,9`

Comment: This might be a bit more understandable: `sed -i -r ':a;s/([0-9])([0-9]{3})\>/\1,\2/;ta'` -- find a number followed by 3 numbers followed by a word boundary, and insert a comma before the group of 3 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matching is greedy, i.e. it matches the leftmost three digits **NOT preceded by a word boundary** and  **followed by the word boundary**, i.e. the rightmost three digits. After inserting the comma, the  "goto" makes it match again, but the comma introduced a new word boundary, so the match happens earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Bisecting this command:

```
sed -i ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta' numbers.txt

-i     # inline editing to save changes in input file
\B     # opposite of \b (word boundary) - to match between words
[0-9]  # match any digit
\{3,\} # match exact 3 digits
\>     # word boundary
&      # use matched pattern in replacement
:a     # start label a
ta     # go back to label a until \B[0-9]\{3\}\> is matches
```

Yes indeed this sed command starts match/replacement from right most 3 digits and keeps going left till it finds 3 digits.

---

**Update:** However looking at this **inefficient** sed command in a loop I recommend this **much simpler and faster awk** instead:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+$/{printf "%\047.f\n", $1}' file
20,130,607,215,015
607,220,701
992,171
```

Where input file is:

```
cat file
20130607215015
607220701
992171
```

Comment: thanks for such a clear explanation, but why does this parse correctly right to left rather than the other way around?

Comment: That is because of `\B` (between word) on LHS and `\>` (word boundary) on RHS.

Comment: The `\B` is crucial, otherwise sed gets stuck in an infinite loop on the number "123"